# Correlating log entries, such as failed login attempts efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mongodb, nosql

I am looking for an efficient way to identify account brute forcing. 
My log database contains authentication log entries. Each entry has:

- time stamp
- username
- IP address
- login attempt results (success / fail )

I want to produce a report which indicates that which logins have been attacked. Attacked is defined as: unsuccessful login attempts not followed by a successful login attempt within N minutes (e.g. 10) from same IP address. The test cases are:

- user/ip combo has attempted to login unsuccessfully twice and succeeded on third time (no attack)
- user/ip combo has attempted to login unsuccessfully twice and succeeded on third time, while same user, but different ip has tried to unsuccessfully log in  (attack on second user/ip combo)

I can imagine one solution with O(n*log(N)) solution: a cursor goes over each record and then does lookups with another cursor for later records to determine activity. Quite inefficient.

DB doesn't matter: SQL, MySQL, nosql, etc as data can be converted easily.

Answer (score 2):

Group log items by 5min time intervals. For all groups which exceed half your alarming thresholds perform a more expensive but entirely correct check.

That will probably filter out almost all log items which are not a real attack. And a grouping operation is easy to program and quick to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much work you're willing to spend on this Complex Event Processing could be an option. Theres frameworks such as [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) if you do Java.

The idea is to create an event stream based on your server logs (or SQL result) and have Esper check for correlations. [See example query](http://esper.codehaus.org/tutorials/solution_patterns/solution_patterns.html#aggregate-0).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd like to spend close to nothing ;) It is more of a quick hack for me